# Why is visual studio not aware that an integer's value is changing? (debugging)

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2010

I have a few simple lines of code (below). [bp] indicates a breakpoint.

```
     for(int i=0;i<300;i++){}
     int i=0;
     cout<<i;
[bp] for (i=0;i<200;i++){}
```

When I debug this in visual studio, it tells me that i is equal to 300 on the breakpoint. Annoyingly, 0 is printed to the console. Is there any way to make it realize that two variables in different scopes can actually have the same name?

I also want to add some code to the second loop and then debug it - but when I try to do that, i is consistently shown as 300. Very annoying.

Comment: Please don't actually have code like this; it's really confusing (even if it should work, which I'm not sure about). Use seperate variable names, or declare a common local variable at the top of the function.

Comment: I realize it's confusing and not a good way to write production code. I'm simply wondering why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in my visual studio, looking at the debugger Locals window

```
        i   300 int
        argc    1   int
        argv    0x00214b88  wchar_t * *
        i   0   int
```

NOTE! there are two i varibles in the debug output, i == 300  and i == 0

I'm thinking the reason its getting confused is a quirk/bug of the debugger where it tracks both i's  then gets confused when you hover over an i, it just returns the first i?  or some such,  I don't think its semantically checking which i to show.

Comment: Yup - incrediman has hit on a corner case that the debugger doesn't  handle well. He may want to bug this on connect.microsoft.com.

Answer (score 1):

If your breakpoint is on the

```
for (i=0;i<200;i++){}
```

line, that means that the new `i` hasn't initialized yet when the breakpoint is hit, because that line of code hasn't executed yet.  So it's still carrying the original `i` value.

Comment: The new `i` isn't initialized yet even though it was initialized after the first for loop, and before the breakpoint? Not sure I understand. Can you please expand on this?

Comment: But why isn't it using the `i` declared above the `cout`? Why is it using the value from the earlier loop?

Comment: Good question.  Almost looks like it's reusing the loop-scoped i, doesn't it?

Comment: @Robert Yeah, It's weird. But I've not done much C++. I just tested it, however, and it does happen. The second declaration is ignored (I don't get 0 printed, like he says he does). I suppose there is a reason, but I don't know it.

Comment: So you've got three different i's in there.  Do we even need to continue this conversation?

Comment: @Dave: That's pretty messed up, if it's true.

Comment: @Robert: The second `i` is initialized on line 2 and there are only 2 variables. Also, the scope of the first `i` is limited to the first for-statement in any *compliant* compiler.

Comment: Plus remember that it's _outputting_ as expected. Like I said in my question just the debugger was misbehaving.

Answer (score 0):

### **Brace** for impact

---

The use of the same varibale for different perpose at different places in code is **NOT** ideal.

Here's the solution though:
Use braces to separate the different use-cases of the same variable.

```
for(int i=0;i<300;i++){}

{
     int i=0;
     cout<<i;
}

{
[bp] for (i=0;i<200;i++){}
}
```

**NOTE:**
As Robert rightly pointed out, unless the instruction is executed,
**i** will not be initialised to the new value.

GoodLUCK!!

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. Edit: No it doesn't, actually. Can you explain why 0 was cout'd, but 300 was displayed by the debugger?

Comment: With that variation there is no variable `i` in scope for the second loop. Also, the variables are already scoped sufficiently in the OP, the scope of the first `i` is limited to the first for-statement... its just a debugger issue.

Comment: Also as keith says above, it might also be an issue with the debugger tooltip implementation...

Answer (score 0):

The third `i` can alias the first `i`, because they have non-overlapping scopes. The second `i` cannot alias the third, because their scopes *do* overlap.

Hence, the compiler knows it needs to allocate storage for at least two integers. The space for the first integer can be shared by the first and third `i`, and the the space for the second `i` is reserved exclusively for the second `i`. These locations could be registers or stack slots, without loss of generality.

*Interim conclusion: for the compiler, it doesn't matter how often you use the name i. It only cares how many variables you have, and how their scopes overlap.*

So, when the debugger hits the second for-loop, it sees that you're watching the third `i`. The debugger looks up the location of the third `i`. Since that location was also used for the first `i`, it still contains 300. That of course doesn't matter for the program, as you start out by writing 0 to the third `i`, overwriting the old value 300 in that location.

So, the essential step is understanding how variables can be mapped to locations.

Comment: What third `i`? There are only two declared.

Comment: There's an i in the first loop (declared), a second i between the for loops and a third one in the second for-loop. Perhaps I should have clarified more that the third `i` isn't declared in a C++ sense. It's a third variable when it comes to assignment of locations. This is the case because there's no dataflow dependence between them. Google for Static Single Assignment (SSA) for a more detailed explanation how a single name can map to two variables at compiler level. SSA takes the idea to an extreme (each variable is defined by a single unique write) but the concept is more general.